# How to prevent user from clicking Navigation buttons in Android

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-fullscreen, android-immersive

I have encountered a problem where user will exit my application accidentally. I know Android is preventing to block use of these buttons, because you should always be able to exit your app somehow but I am creating an app for blind and visually impaired people and I will implement a special exit the app so they won't close it when they will be using it.

Here are some things I gathered:

- I can block the `onBackPressed()` function and prevent going back.
- I can't use `onKeyEvent()` since it won't grab the home click
- Good example is MX Player where you can "lock" your screen but it just draws over the whole screen, thus preventing user to click on anything.

Ok, so I would like to grab the same thing as MX Player, except, I would like for user, to still have interaction with the screen.

I tried using `Immersive full screen` that Google has introduced for full screen apps, but whenever user slides his finger on the screen, `Navigation Menu` popus up. Can I keep this hidden at all times? Also, can I prevent the slide from `Status Bar` to display the buttons? I would like to have full control of how the user is moving their finger over the screen.

So if I go back to the MX Player solution - drawing over the screen. Can I create like a `Canvas` that doesn't have focus and it's just there to prevent the clicks on the buttons?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "I am creating an app for blind and visually impaired people" -- most likely, those users are used to the navigation buttons working. After all, they will work in all the other apps that they use, and they work well with existing Talkback and related accessibility support. Why do you feel that your users will want your app to block access to those options?

Comment: Idk, I am working with this one blind guy, who is testing the app, and he told me it would be best to hide it, since some important feature is right next to it. If he closes it, it's hard to get it back up. I have currently installed AutoStart to start it when phone starts, so he doesn't have to look for it. Also, TalkBack is not yet supported in my app, and I have setup my own TTS for now. Oh, and he is an iOS user and my app is currently for Android only, maybe that's why it bothers him?

Comment: "since some important feature is right next to it" -- then move the important feature elsewhere.

Comment: Well we did the interface for tablets at first and everything was ok, but now we wanted to make it available for phones as well and the feature is on the same side but the Navigation Bar moved to the side as well. Screen is full of features and I can't go move it just as I please since there is no place to move it... If you have any ideas, I am happy to hear them, if you don't have a solution, thanks for reading my post

Comment: "I can't go move it just as I please since there is no place to move it" -- sure there is. Put it higher on the screen, away from the bottom, where it might interfere with navigation options. Redesigning a UI when switching between form factors (tablet to phone to watch to TV to desktop to car to...) is usually required. Breaking phone functionality is not an acceptable substitute.